# guardar un array de forms con checkbox

Tags: php, array, checkbox

Tengo que guardar varios formularios al mismo tiempo y cada formulario contienen multiples checkbox que cuando son todos seleccionados se guardan correctamente pero cuando alguno queda vació marca error alguien me pede auxiliar[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son los formularios que envió al mismo tiempo:

```
  <tbody>
                  <tr class="active">
                    <input type="hidden" id="id_us_res" name="id_us_res[]" value="<?php echo $row1['id_usuario_reservacion']; ?>">
                    <td>
                      Usuario<br>
                      <?php echo $row1['nombre_usuario']; ?>
                      <input type="hidden" id="nom_usu" name="nom_usu[]" value="<?php echo $row1['nombre_usuario']; ?>">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Personaje<br>
                      <?php echo $row1['nombre_personaje']; ?>
                      <input type="hidden" id="nom_per" name="nom_per[]" value="<?php echo $row1['nombre_personaje']; ?>">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Vacunas<br>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="pildora[]" name="pildora[]" value="pildora"> Pildora<br>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="antivirus[]" name="antivirus[]" value="antivirus"> Antivirus<br>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div><!-- /example -->
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if($_SESSION['tipo_usuario']==1) { ?>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Guardar Partida </button>
            <?php } ?>
            </form>
```

Este es el error que sale:

[image: mensaje de error]

Aquí está mi código:

```
$id_us_res = $_GET['id_us_res'];
$nom_usu = $_GET['nom_usu'];
$nom_per = $_GET['nom_per'];
$pildora = isset($_GET['pildora']) ? $_GET['pildora'] : 0;
$antivirus = isset($_GET['antivirus']) ? $_GET['antivirus'] : 0;


for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($id_us_res); ++$i)
{
echo "<br>" . $sql = "INSERT INTO ranking (id_usuario_ranking, nombre_usuario, nombre_personaje, Pildora, Antivirus)
           VALUES ('$id_us_res[$i]','$nom_usu[$i]','$nom_per[$i]','$pildora[$i]','$antivirus[$i]')";
           $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

}
```

Comment: Hola, si le das formato al código de tu pregunta va a ser mas fácil conseguir ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el ciclo `for` tienes que revisar con `isset` si tienes un valor antes de usarlo en la consulta. Algo así:

```
for ($i = 0; $i<sizeof($id_us_res); ++$i) {

    $pil = isset($pildora[$i])   ? $pildora[$i]   : '';
    $ant = isset($antivirus[$i]) ? $antivirus[$i] : '';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ranking 
            (id_usuario_ranking, nombre_usuario, nombre_personaje, Pildora, Antivirus)
            VALUES
            ('$id_us_res[$i]','$nom_usu[$i]','$nom_per[$i]','$pil','$ant')";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Undefined offset significa que estas solicitando una posición que no existe dentro de un arreglo, en la linea 28 de tu código (no se cual es la linea 28 de tu código) estas haciendo algo como:

```
$a = $miarreglo[2];
```

Pero mi $miarreglo no tiene la posición 2.